# How to call an annotation with a parameter from a custom annotation?

Tags: spring, annotations

How can I create a @CustomAnnotation with parameters that triggers another annotation such as @Bean(parameterFromCustomAnnotation)?

Is that even possible?

```
@Bean # How to add a parameter from the MyBean annotation to @Bean?
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class, timeout = 5)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyBean{}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find below the example :

1st Step : Create your Custom Annotation :

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface DummyService
{
    APIServiceName serviceName() ;
}
```

2nd Step : Create your parameters

```
 public enum APIServiceName
{
    ADD_USER,
    GET_USER_BY_ID
}
```

3rd Step : User your Custom Annotations for API's

```
 @DummyService(serviceName = APIServiceName.ADD_USER)
    @RequestMapping(value = /addUSer, method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody dummyResponse addUserToDB(@RequestBody String userReq, HttpServletRequest request) {
  logic goes here
}
```